# Automatically switch to logarithmic scale when range is too large

Tags: gnuplot, logarithm

I have a generic script that creates a Gnuplot macro.

Is there a way to automatically switch to logarithmic scale for the y-axis when the range is to large—let's say, more than two orders of magnitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already got it:

```
if(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN>100) set logscale
```

does the job.

Comment: Do you get those variables before the plot? Or you plot first a dummy plot to compute them?